# Encoding/Decoding URL between Play Backend and JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, url-encoding

I've I Play REST API and a JavaScript client that sends a token:signature pair in the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/auth/users/all/0/11?auth=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N...ciOiJIU:8so/gRFwOoPXp2x6RfyUpMYIMD4=
```

In the JavaScript client I encode the URL like this:

```
signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(token + method + obj.url.slice(baseUrl.length) + body, apiKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
...
obj.url = obj.url + (obj.url.indexOf("?") > 0 ? "&" : "?") + "auth=" + encodeURIComponent(token + ":" + signature);
```

Then, in the Play backend I decode the URL like this:

```
import java.nio.charset.{StandardCharsets => SC}
import play.utils.UriEncoding

// auth(0) => token, auth(1) => signature
val auth = UriEncoding.decodePathSegment(jwt, SC.US_ASCII.name).split(":")
```

The problem is that `UriEncoding` crashes because of the slash:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1:
Execution exception[[InvalidUriEncodingException: Cannot decode eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N...vZ5v18d2EZik1ki5W9_6XABi-JA:8so/gRFwOoPXp2x6RfyUpMYIMD4=: illegal character at position 715.]]
```

Now my questions are:

1. In the JavaScript client should I base64 before encoding the URL with `encodeURIComponent`?
2. In the Play backend, what encoding should I use, `US_ASCII` or `UTF_8`?

Answer (score 4):

Just replaced `UriEncoding.decodePathSegment` with `UriEncoding.decodePath` and it works:

```
import java.nio.charset.{StandardCharsets => SC}
import play.utils.UriEncoding

// auth(0) => token, auth(1) => signature
val auth = UriEncoding.decodePath(jwt, SC.US_ASCII.name).split(":")
```

I hope it helps.